# WebApi serialization for DateTime - how to deserialize?

Tags: .net, datetime

This code:

```
public class PhotoDescriptor
{
    public DateTime DateCreatedUtc { get; set; }
}

public class PhotosController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/photos
    public IEnumerable<PhotoDescriptor> GetListOfPhotos()
    {
        return new PhotoDescriptor[]
            {
                new PhotoDescriptor
                    {
                        DateCreatedUtc = DateTime.ParseExact(
                                "2012-07-24T00:28:41.8738770Z",
                                "o",
                                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                DateTimeStyles.None).ToUniversalTime(),
                    },
                new PhotoDescriptor
                    {
                        DateCreatedUtc = DateTime.ParseExact(
                                "2012-07-24T00:28:41.0000000Z",
                                "o",
                                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                DateTimeStyles.None).ToUniversalTime(),
                    },
            };
    }
```

returns the following JSON:

```
[{"DateCreatedUtc":"2012-07-24T00:28:41.873877Z"},
 {"DateCreatedUtc":"2012-07-24T00:28:41Z"}]
```

**notice that trailing zeros were removed from the datetime**. But when I'm trying to parse these strings to get my DateTime back, I get `FormatException - String was not recognized as a valid DateTime`:

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact("2012-07-24T00:28:41.873877Z", "o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

which is correct, according to MSDN [DateTime.ParseExact Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131038.aspx):

> ***FormatException***
>
> s does not contain a date and time that corresponds to
>   the pattern specified in format.

and `"o"` format [is defined](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#Roundtrip) as follows:

> yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fffffffK

so clearly trailing zeros SHOULD be there.

Is it a bug in WebApi, or am I doing something wrong? And how should I pass date/time field to my .Net client?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you're parsing the hard-coded values appropriately - but your code shows nothing about how they should be written out in JSON. Your "should be" claim is only with respect to the format you're *parsing* in, which of course isn't propagated within the `DateTime` itself.

If you want to parse the values yourself (and I have to ask why that's not being done for you...) you can use `F` instead of `f`:

```
DateTime value = DateTime.ParseExact(text, 
                                     "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'FFFFFFFK",
                                     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I'm not saying it *isn't* a bug in WebApi - but I haven't seen any indication that it *is* a bug in WebApi from your post... and [Scott Hanselman's post on dates in WebApi](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx) give examples which are "just down to the second", suggesting that's deliberate.